# Forma correcta de redactar cuando forma singular y plural de los artículos y sustantivos son posibles en el contexto?

Tags: sustantivos, plurales, artículos, redacción

ni siquiera sé cómo formular esta pregunta, pero quisiera saber cuál es la forma más correcta de escribir en los casos en que en el contexto la forma plural y singular son posibles en los artículos y sustantivos, por ejemplo "la(s) casa(s)" o "la/las casa/casas" o se debe escribir de otra forma?. Gracias.

Comment: Nos tienes que dar ejemplos.  Pero te ofrezco algunas frases tomadas del aire.  *Cada quien se fue a su casa.  Las dos comentamos ayer que va a hcer mucha falta limpiar la casa cuando terminemos con los exámenes.  En California, las casas son pequeñitas.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según el DPD, [ambas formas son correctas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XFiqsCjr2D68AoepU2):

> **PARÉNTESIS**
>   **2. Usos.**
>   **c)** Para introducir opciones en un texto. En estos casos se encierra entre paréntesis el elemento que constituye la alternativa, sea este una palabra completa, sea uno de sus segmentos: *En el documento se indicará(n) el (los) día(s) en que haya tenido lugar la baja; Se necesita chico(a) para repartir pedidos.* Como se ve en los ejemplos, los paréntesis que añaden segmentos van pegados a la palabra a la que se refieren. En este uso, el paréntesis puede alternar con la barra (→ [barra](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bYvzHZDvGD6fr29gvU), 1b).